# What is the best Drupal module that allows me to embedd videos from Youtube or upload videos locally?

Tags: drupal, video, drupal-7

What is the best available Drupal module that allows the user the ability to either upload the video locally or embed a video from a thirty-party video sharing website (ex: Youtube) 2- Is this video integrated with players such as flow-player? 3- Can the video be transcoded to flv or mp4?

Comment: Hey, as Alexandru said, Media and MediaYoutube are great. Here is a tutorial i did on setting the up: http://cleverlogic.net/tutorials/drupal-7-video-setup-using-media-and-media-youtube-module

Comment: I had put a comment on cleverlogic. My Problems now lies in the fact that I don't know how I can display both the embedded videos and uploaded videos in the same view. I would appreciate if you can make a video tutorial which shows how this can be done.

Comment: Hey, that should be quite simple, just add both fields to the view (the one with embedded and the one with uploaded videos), if the node has embedded vids, it would show up, and if its a node with uploaded vids, the uploaded vids would show up too.

Comment: Thanks. After getting it to work, I have written a tutorial about it on my website http://linux-hosting.net/article/uploading-embedding-and-playing-videos-drupal .

Comment: You might want to addd a link to the tutorial as a comment on cleverlogic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module plus the extension module [MediaYoutube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube)

To transcode the video to flv or mp4 you will need [ffmpeg](http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-ffmpeg-php/).

> ffmpeg is a very powerful tool to record, convert and stream audio and video. Its a very rich tool almost supporting every format out there in the world.

Or, if you think you're up-to, you can try [Kaltura](http://www.kaltura.org/) witch is an open source video platform that can be integrated with almost all CMSs ([Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/kaltura), [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/), [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) etc). It will take care of uploaded videos for you.